# Number of Points Inside a Rectangle

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry

This question is from a Japanese contest:

> Let $S$ be a set of 2002  points in the coordinate plane, no two of which have the same $x$- or $y$- coordinate. For any two points $P,Q$ in $S$ consider the rectangle with one diagonal $PQ$ and sides parallel to the axes. Let $W_{PQ}$ be the number of points of $S$ lying in the interior of this rectangle. Find the maximum $N$ such that, no matter how the points of $S$ are distributed, there always exist points $A,B$ in $S$ with $W_{AB}\geq N$.

I think the answer is 43 (but I'm not so sure). Actually consider a set $S$ with $f(n)$ points. Let be $f(n)$ the minimum number of points such that there always exist points $A,B$ in $S$ with $W_{AB}\geq n$. I believe $f(n)=(n+1)^2+1$. The fact that $f(n)\leq (n+1)^2+1$ follows from Erdos-Szekeres theorem. The hard part is to find an example of $S$ with $(n+1)^2$ points such that $W_{AB}\leq n-1$ for all points $A,B$ in $S$ (I'm also not sure this is true for all $n$).

For $n=1$ take $S= \{(1,3),(2,1),(3,4),(4,2) \}.$
For $n=2$ take $S= \{(1,6),(2,7),(3,2),(4,1),(5,5),(6,9),(7,8),(8,3),(9,4)\}.$
For $n=3$ I don't know an example.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Doesn't it work for the set of points $a_{i,j}=((n+1)i+j, (n+1)j-i)$ for $0\leq i,j \leq n$?

Comment: @emeu I don't think so. Following your example for $n=2$ we have $S={(0,0), (1,3), (2,6), (3,-1), (4,2), (5,5), (6,-2), (7,1), (8,4)}$. Let $A=(2,6)$, $B=(6,-2)$. In this case $W_{AB}=3$.

Comment: Indeed, my suggestion was wrong. Thanks for the counterexeample.